# Java - Find specific files (based on conditions) inside a given folder

Tags: java, file

I have a code where I'm given:
 - "Name"
 - "extension"
 - "directory path".
I'd need to find all files in "directory path", that have "Name" as a substring of their file name and of type "extension".
I found similar questions on the web, but not one with this kind of conditions requirements.

Comment: Using Java 7, you can walk the file tree in the given directory and match the conditions that you are looking for. Visit: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html

Comment: Usually, when you ask on SO, you provide some code that you had wrote, and help you diagnose why it doesn't work. Nobody is going to write the code (which looks like homework) for you.

Comment: Can you show your progress and where you are stucked at?

Comment: I'm currently translating and old code from Delphi to Java for my job, and I'm quite new to both. So I'm sorry, but I'm stuck at the start.. :/
But just a direction as @inquizitive provided is already appreciated :D I'll work on it.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you get your 3 variables via command line parameters, you could use this type of approach:

```
package com.sample.stack;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

public class FileRenamenter {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String name = args[0]; // usefull, just to be clear
        final String extension = args[1]; // usefull, just to be clear
        final String directoryPath = args[2]; // usefull, just to be clear
        File directory = new File(directoryPath);
        // obtaing list of file wich name contain your «name» as substring
        String[] list = directory.list(new FilenameFilter(){
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                boolean matchExtension = name.endsWith(extension);
                boolean containsName = name.substring(0, name.length() - extension.length()).contains(name);
                return matchExtension && containsName;
            }
        });
        // echo file list
        for (String filePath : list) {
            System.out.println(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```